# Print a 3d plot in Octave after rotating

Tags: 3d, plot, rotation, octave

I have an Octave script that plots a curve in 3-dimensional space. When the plot window comes up, I can manually rotate and zoom using the mouse, but if I go back to the Octave shell and type

```
print("filename.png", "-dpng");
```

then it prints the graph using the default camera position and angle, and NOT the view that I changed it to by dragging with the mouse.  Does anyone know how to print the graph AS YOU SEE IT in the plotting window?

Comment: The [`saveas`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/saveas.html) function might help. Nevertheless, Octave 3.2.4 on Windows could not find this function so I cannot test it at this moment. It may be present on a newer version or on another platform.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the view function to change the plot's p.o.v.
To do this you can move the image using the mouse as you would normally do, then look at the bottom left corner of the plot and write down the two view numbers (assume a and b).
Then before printing, simply use the command view(b,90-a) (notice you have to swap the numbers and subtract the second from 90.